# how to find the maximum of simultaneous TCP connections supportable by a system?

Tags: networking, tcp

I was wondering, admitting an address system translation which uses public address in order to offer an access to Internet to 15 computers, how could I find the maximum of simultaneous TCP connections supportable by this system please?

I am beginner with network and not able to find an answer to that, although I was thinking, a TCP connection can handle 65 535 simultaneous connections, since there is 15 computers then I get : **65 535/15 = 4369**, is that correct?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It does not work that way. For example, an HTTP server uses port 80, but it could have many thousands or millions (depending on the server resources) of TCP connections connecting to port 80.

Answer (score 1):

The things you called "address system translation" always named as NAT(Netowrk Address Translation) devices such as routers.

A network connection is checked by the tuple of five elements: Source IP, Source Port, Destination IP, Destination Port, and Protocol. So the limitation of connection numbers is decided by these elements.

You said 65536 connetions, this is the limitation of ports.

For a Circumstance like you said, 1 router with 1 external IP, for every one of the 15 PC inside of the NAT LAN, the circumstances is like:

Source IP is the router's external IP
Source Port has at max 65536 choices
Destination IP is limited by the IPV4 or IPV6 address length
Destination Port is limited by 65536
Protocol can choose TCP/UDP

So you can see, in theory we can have millions of connections for every PC. But the thing is that we need to consider the limitation of hardware, OS and virtual memory, so we can't have so much.

Comment: That would be the NAPT variant of NAT. There are three tables (TCP, UDP, and ICMP). Standard NAT does not deal with the transport protocol, only the IPv4 address (IPv6 does not have a NAT standard, only an experimental RFC, and it explicitly forbids NAPT for IPv6).